# PHP stream websockets

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

Im kinda new with the sockets stuff and Im trying to make a server on PHP to support websockets calls from my javascript currently my code looks like this

```
<?php

class Websocket
{
    private $server;

    private $sockets = [];

    public function create($host)
    {
        $this->server = stream_socket_server('tcp://localhost:8080', $errno, $errmsg);
        stream_set_blocking($this->server, 0);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            $client = stream_socket_accept($this->server);

            if($client)
            {
                $data = stream_socket_recvfrom($client, 2048);

                if($data)
                {
                    echo 'Client connected'.PHP_EOL;
                                        echo $data;
                    $response = $this->handshake($data);

                    stream_socket_sendto($client, $response);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function handshake($data)
    {
        $data = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);

        foreach($data as $header)
        {
            $current_header = explode(':', $header);

            if($current_header[0] == 'Sec-WebSocket-Key')
            {
                $accept = base64_encode(sha1(trim($current_header[1]).'258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11', true));
                $response = 'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols'.PHP_EOL.'Upgrade: websocket'.PHP_EOL.'Connection: Upgrade'.PHP_EOL.'Sec-WebSocket-Accept:'.$accept.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

                return $response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my javascript is just a simple

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

socket.onopen = function(event) 
{
    console.log('connected');
    socket.send('hello');
}
```

Currently the message connected appears on my chrome console but after that when the hello message is supposed to be sent I get this error

"connection to: xxx was interrupted while the page was loading"

So my question is after I have successfully send the handshake to the client how do I process messages? I know my code is always sending the handshake to new connections but on my server I will only see the first message beeing echoed (the http request) and not the "hello" one

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the message -

```
socket.onmessage = function(e){
   var server_message = e.data;
   console.log(server_message);
}
```

Comment: Well that logs nothing into my console. Since the client is the one sending the message why would I need to handle it?. Thanks